# Rational points inside a special integral quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rational-numbers, geometric-topology

Let $P=(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ be a simple polygon drawn on a plane.

- The co-ordinates of the vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ are all integers.
- The lengths of the edges $(v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), (v_3, v_4)$ and $(v_4, v_1)$ are all integers.
- The distance between $v_1$ and $v_3$ is an integer.

**Conjecture 1**: There exists a point $x$ with rational coordinates **inside** $P$ such that the euclidean distances between the pairs $(x, v_1), (x, v_2), (x, v_3)$ and $(x, v_4)$ are all rational numbers.

**Conjecture 2**: There exists infinite such points $x$ in $P$.

**Conjecture 3**: All such points $x$ in $P$ are dense in the plane of the polygon $P$.

**Conjecture 4**: Above conjectures when the polygon $P$ is convex.

My Questions:

- Are the above conjectures true ?
- Are there any similar known conjectures or results ?